# How to display Appboy HTML inAppMessage in React JS app

Tags: reactjs, appboy, braze

I need to to show a braze inAppMessage HTML pop up in my React JS application. here is my code base

```
export const displayCustomInAppHTMLMessage = msgTxt => {
  const message = new appboy.HtmlMessage(msgTxt);
  appboy.display.showInAppMessage(message);
};
```

But this does not show any pop up. Can someone please help?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To show the HTML inAppMessage we need to set `enableHtmlInAppMessages` to `true` while initialisation code

https://www.braze.com/docs/user_guide/message_building_by_channel/in-app_messages/customize/#custom-html-messages